# writeToFile path?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, filesystems

I'm wondering what is the default path when saving a file using the NSArray writeToFile:atomically: method...?

```
[array writeToFile:@"myFile.plist" atomically:YES];
```

10x

Comment: In the simulator it writes to `/` on my HD.

Comment: Ntg will be provided as a default path

Comment: @Nick - nice :) and on the device?
@AAAA- Ntg ?

Comment: see my answer below, the method returned NO so it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed the following code:

```
if ([@"asdasdasd" writeToFile:@"foo123456.txt" atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"+++");
} else {
    NSLog(@"---");
}
```

On the simulator the file `foo123456.txt` popped up in my root of my HD. The console printed `+++`, so the operation was successful.

On the device it failed, printing `---`.

Comment: writeToFile:atomically is indeed deprecated as for NSString, but not for NSArray.

Comment: @Rizon Mixed device with sim, lol, and I approved of the editing by you and now I can't edit my own post :)

Comment: :D, so this is not what you meant?

Comment: Yes it was, but the deprecation note had to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

It will save your file at Document directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

this is the path where your file will be saved.

Comment: on the device? because on the simulator unfortunately you're wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

plistpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Product.plist"]];
```

And then

```
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; 

[Whatever [Array or Dictionary] you want to Write in Plist]
```

If it is still not creating the plist then check whether your array or dictionary must be empty.